# PWA service worker doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I have this code for add to home screen using service worker and `PWA`:

```
function isFacebookApp() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
    return (ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1);
}
if (window.location.protocol == "https:" && window.isSecureContext) {
    if (!isFacebookApp()) {
        if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
                console.log("[PWA Builder] active service worker found, no need to register");
            } else {
                navigator.serviceWorker.register("/sw.js").then(function(reg) {
                    console.log("[PWA Builder] Service worker has been registered for scope: " + reg.scope);
                });
            }
        }
    } else {
        console.log("[PWA Builder] The current browser doesn\'t support service workers.");
    }
} else {
    console.log("[PWA Builder] The web site is not served from a secure (HTTPS) domain.");
}
```

In sw.js:

```
const CACHE = "pwabuilder-page";
const offlineFallbackPage = ["/"];
self.addEventListener("install", function (event) {
  console.log("[PWA Builder] Install Event processing");

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
      console.log("[PWA Builder] Cached offline page during install");

      if (offlineFallbackPage === "offline.html") {
        return cache.add(
          new Response(
            "TODO: Update the value of the offlineFallbackPage constant in the serviceworker."
          )
        );
      }

      return cache.add(offlineFallbackPage);
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  if (event.request.method !== "GET") return;

  event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).catch(function (error) {
      if (
        event.request.destination !== "document" ||
        event.request.mode !== "navigate"
      ) {
        return;
      }

      console.error(
        "[PWA Builder] Network request Failed. Serving offline page " + error
      );
      return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
        return cache.match(offlineFallbackPage);
      });
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener("refreshOffline", function () {
  const offlinePageRequest = new Request(offlineFallbackPage);

  return fetch(offlineFallbackPage).then(function (response) {
    return caches.open(CACHE).then(function (cache) {
      console.log(
        "[PWA Builder] Offline page updated from refreshOffline event: " +
          response.url
      );
      return cache.put(offlinePageRequest, response);
    });
  });
});

self.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown() {
  var history = App.getHistory();
  if (history.length === 1) {
    var history_screen = history[0];
    if (
      TemplateTags.getDefaultRouteLink().replace("#", "") ===
      history_screen.fragment
    ) {
      navigator.app.exitApp();
      return;
    }
  }
  navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```

In action my code working in `chrome` and `Edge` browser(mobile and desktop version) But in `Firefox` I can't see add to home screen notification and it doesn't work. how do can I fix this problem?!